# Does Laravel remove a record from the queue at the start of the worker processing it or after the worker has finished processing it?

Tags: laravel, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to figure out if the worker removes the record from the queue after it's completed processing the record or when it pulls the record off of the queue.

My contention is that it pulls the record off of the queue when it begins to process the record so as to prevent other workers from using that record.

If possible any chance of finding where in the source that happens so I can show people?

Comment: You ask for source reference but you don't need us, just open up the [Laravel repository](https://github.com/laravel/framework/search?q=sqs&unscoped_q=sqs) and browse through it and make sure you are looking for sqs driver. What does this mean *If possible any chance of finding where in the source that happens so I can show people?* are you asking on behalf of someone? I bet my 5 cents that it does not remove the job but sets a flag "working on the job" so if you run multiple workers job is not pulled multiple times.

Comment: Interesting. 

Thanks for the feedback.
Yep just want to show my team. We're designing a heavily concurrent system and were hoping to avoid duplicates being pulled off queues.

And I think you're right it just sets a flag but was hoping for confirmation from more knowledgable people.

Comment: I can talk only about redis / database driver and in fact it is popped -> processed and if it fails its inserted back (for database "with new id").

Comment: Interesting.  So it is removed from the queue, then processed, then replaced back on the queue if it fails.